# Connection between left null space and matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This question comes from Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra, 5th edition" (3.5, exercise 20)

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = ER$
>
> How many independent solutions to $A^T \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}$? Why does $\mathbf{y}^T = \text{row } 3 \text{ of } E^{-1}$?

Based on the two matrices $E$ and $R$ I can see $\text{rank}(A) = 2$ so the left null-space of $A$ (i.e. the nullspace of $A^T$) has dimension $3 - 2 = 1$, so it has one "independent solution" to $A^T \mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}$.

However, I am stuck in showing how $\mathbf{y}^T$ is equal to row 3 of $E^{-1}$. The instrutor manual solution for the exercise states: "*$E^{-1}A = R$ has a zero row, which is just the transpose of $A^{T}\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{0}$*". I am unsure what he means here.

Thus, I wanted to ask if anyone could clarify what is stated in the manual or any tips on approaching the problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $\mathbf{y}^TER=\mathbf{0}$. We can define $\mathbf{u}^T=\mathbf{y}^TE$ so that $\mathbf{u}^TR=\mathbf{0}$, and it is clear that the solution set is generated by $\mathbf{u}^T=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Because $E$ is invertible, we then have $\mathbf{y}^T=\mathbf{u}^TE^{-1}$, from which the result follows.

**Added:** I've been trying to make sense of the solution manual's statement. It is indeed the case that $E^{-1}A=R$ has a zero row, namely its third row, a row of four zeroes. It is also true that $\mathbf{y}^{T}A$, which is the transpose of $A^T\mathbf{y}$, is a row of four zeroes. So the third row of $E^{-1}A$ is the same as $\mathbf{y}^{T}A$. Now the third row of $R$ is the result of multiplying the third row of $E^{-1}$ by $A$. So we can take $\mathbf{y}^T$ to be the third row of $E^{-1}$ (or any scalar multiple thereof).

Answer (score 1):

The question is incorrect as written: there is a line of solutions to $A^T \mathbf y = 0$, one of these is such that $\mathbf y^T$ is row $3$ of $E^{-1}$. Also, the solution from the manual is incomprehensible (at least to me).

Here is what I think Strang is getting at. Note that $A^T\mathbf y = 0 \iff \mathbf y^TA = 0$, which we can write as
$$
(\mathbf y^T E)R = \mathbf 0.
$$
Now, a convenient way to select $\mathbf y$ is to select it so that the above product becomes
$$
[0 \ \ 0 \ \ 1] \ R,
$$
since for any matrix $M$ of $3$ rows, $[0 \ \ 0 \ \ 1] M$ is simply the third row of $M$. In other words, an easy solution is to choose $\mathbf y$ such that $\mathbf y^T E = [0 \ \ 0 \ \ 1]$.  Now, note that if we let $\mathbf r_1, \mathbf r_2, \mathbf r_3$ denote the rows of $E^{-1}$, then we have
$$
E^{-1}E = I \implies \pmatrix{\mathbf r_1\\ \mathbf r_2\\ \mathbf r_3} E = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1} \implies
\pmatrix{\mathbf r_1 E\\ \mathbf r_2 E\\ \mathbf r_3 E} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1}.
$$
Now, if we consider the third row in this last equation, we see that $\mathbf r_3 E = [0 \ \ 0\ \ 1]$. That is, taking $\mathbf y^T$ to be row $3$ of $E^{-1}$ gives us exactly what we're looking for.